# ActionSheetStringPicker change button color

Tags: ios, swift3

```
ActionSheetStringPicker.show(withTitle: "Select Status", rows: pickerData, initialSelection: self.selectedStatusRow, doneBlock: {
                        picker, value, index in                  
                        self.selectedStatusRow = value                                    
                        return
                    }, cancel: { ActionStringCancelBlock in return }, origin: sender)
```

What I want is change the color of cancel and done button in swift 3 while using this library.How can this be done? i need it to take my theme, and global tint color I have.Thank you

Comment: you have to do change into your main library, otherwise there is no option for that

Answer (score 2):

I was searching some example to localize the Default Cancel and Done buttons,  Here is sample code to customize default Cancel and Done Toolbar button of ActionSheetPicker-3.0

```
 @IBAction func showCompanyTypes(_ sender: Any) {

    let cancelButton:UIButton =  UIButton(type: .custom)
    cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
    cancelButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    cancelButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 32)

    let doneButton:UIButton =  UIButton(type: .custom)
    doneButton.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    doneButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    doneButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 32)

    let acp = ActionSheetStringPicker(title: "Company Type", rows: ["Private Sector", "Government", "Semi Government", "Free Zone"], initialSelection: 0, doneBlock: {
        picker, values, indexes in

        print("values = \(values)")
        print("indexes = \(indexes)")
        print("picker = \(picker)")

        return

    }, cancel: { ActionMultipleStringCancelBlock in return }, origin: sender)


    acp?.pickerTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)]
    acp?.setTextColor(UIColor.black)
    acp?.pickerBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    acp?.toolbarBackgroundColor = UIColor.white
    acp?.toolbarButtonsColor = UIColor.black
    acp?.setCancelButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: cancelButton))
    acp?.setDoneButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: doneButton))
    acp?.show()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example project on the Github page:

```
picker.toolbarButtonsColor = UIColor.red
```

https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/blob/master/Example%20Projects/Swift-Example/Swift-Example/ViewControllers/SWTableViewController.swift

Answer (score 0):

A working workaround you can use is to set a tint color to the main window that hosts the action picker, in the `SWActionSheet.m` file as follows:

```
- (UIWindow *)window {

    if ( SWActionSheetWindow )
    {
        return SWActionSheetWindow;
    }
    else
    {
        return SWActionSheetWindow = ({
            UIWindow *window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
            window.windowLevel        = UIWindowLevelAlert;
            window.backgroundColor    = [UIColor clearColor];

            // Window Tint Color.
            [window setTintColor:[UIColor whatEverColor]];

            window.rootViewController = [SWActionSheetVC new];
            window;
        });
    }
}
```

PS. This will set the tint color of the default buttons in every single instance of actionsheetpicker in your project.

Source: https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/issues/54